# Bayesian sequential updating with current Bayesian sampling software?

Tags: bayesian, jags, stan, sequential-analysis

I'm having a hard time implementing sequential updating with current software, I don't even know how to start. Basically, I'm having to refit the whole model by simply appending the new data to the old data.

Surely, there must be a better way to do that. So how can one implement Bayesian sequential updating with current Bayesian sampling software such as JAGS or Stan? Can you show how to do it with a simple numerical example (and code)?

Comment: There exists *sequential monte carlo* methods. I am unaware of any widely available software for SMC but it is quite easy to code up yourself. All you really do is sample with replacement from your current posterior samples according to a set of weights.

Comment: @jcken can you show how to do it in an example using JAGS or STAN?

Comment: As far as I know you can't do SMC in jags or stan. It is just resampling with replacement from the "first" posterior. A good starting point would be here https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/smc_resources.html

Comment: @jcken can you show how one would do this with the output of jags or stan?

Comment: we've diverted a bit from the original question and I'm not an expert in SMC. I think you should ask a fresh question about performing SMC for your model + JAGS output

Comment: @jcken not sure how we diverted from the original question... the question is about implementing SMC with current bayesian software.